# Update array element in arraylist of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, arraylist

I need to update an element of array inside arraylist of arrays

```
ArrayList<Object[]> IT = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
String[] arr1 = {"1" , "2" , "3"};    
String[] arr2 = {"4" , "5" , "6"}; 
String[] arr3 = {"7" , "8" , "9"};
IT.add(arr1); 
IT.add(arr2);
IT.add(arr3);
```

I need to update elements of these internal arrays.

Comment: Good for you. And your question is?

Comment: English probably isn't his first language. I think we can get the gist of what he's asking.

Comment: Which element? And what is the problem? And why are you using `Object[]` instead of `String[]` in your `List`?

Comment: I need the procedure to follow to update any element, this is a sample code just written to clarify my question.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem for yourself?  Edit your question to give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to illustrate the problems you've encountered, and we'll be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like arrays you can access the `ArrayList` elements by their `index`, you can use `get(index)` method, so what you need to do is:

First get the `String[]` from the list with its `index`:

```
IT.get(0)
```

Then get the relevant element to update in this `Array` with its `index` as well:

```
IT.get(0)[1] = "SDSDSD";
```

Answer (score 0):

Its same as **2D array**, the only difference is 1 of the dimension is `ArrayList` instead of `Array`. You need to do it in steps in the order of there definition.

First you need to access the ArrayList by using `IT.get(rowIndex)`, this will return you an array, which you can access using the array syntax for accessing like `arr[columnIndex]`. 
Since the `arr` here is `IT.get(rowIndex)` you access it by

`IT.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex]`

e.g.

```
System.out.println(IT.get(1)[1]); //  Output : 5
```